# MyBatis TypeException when using <foreach>

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

I'm trying to create a SelectStatement in Mybatis 3.5.13 using a foreach iterating over a map, where the keys are Column Names and the values are the value I want to select on.

I've confirmed that all keys and values are not null and are Strings.

My select query:

select * from ${tableName} where

```
    <foreach collection="dataMap.entrySet()" item="value" index="key" open=" " separator=" and " close="">
        #{key} = #{value}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

The error I'm getting is:
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='__frch_key_2', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.String, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null, resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #3 with JdbcType null . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 3.

I tried removing the foreach and replacing it with the query I want MyBatis to create and it works as expected.

Comment: I fixed it. Had to change #{key} to ${key}.